# How to Fastlane re-init? Error: The request could not be completed because: Not Found

Tags: ios, fastlane

I'm trying to automate uploading my iOS App to Testflight by Fastlane.

When I use `fastlane init` , there is 4 options to init.

1. Automate screenshots
2. ‍✈️ Automate beta distribution to TestFlight
3. Automate App Store distribution
4. Manual setup - manually setup your project to automate your tasks

First, I picked 4th option. But I think I want to change to 2nd option because when I picked 4th option, fastlane didn't ask me my apple ID so it has problem to get cert.

So I removed files about Fastlane(Gemfile, Gemfile.lock, AppFile, FastFile). Then I use `fastlane init` again.

Now fastlane asks me my Apple ID and password. But after I entered my ID, fastlane fails with this error: `The request could not be completed because: Not Found`

Also, Fastfile's code about the custom_lane of 4th option remains same after `fastlane init` again.

How to re-init fastlane in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not my installation error. It was a Fastlane's issue.

There was an error that fails to accessing Apple API in Fastlane 2.187 version. It is fixed in 2.188 version